# Find syntactically matching stored procs in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I was Googling around, but couldn't find anything that can help me.
We are using SQL-Server 2008 R2, and it's our policy to use stored procedures for all our database calls.  This works fine, but the problem is now that our list of procedures has grown to over 600, we're making duplicates of syntactically matching queries that someone else (and sometimes ourselves) wrote.

Right now we search for all the procs that contain the same tables and columns as the one we want to create and then see if we can just reuse it, but this is becoming a more and more time consuming activity.  If we try anything more complicated than just searching table/view and column names, then we might miss an existing proc simply due to the syntax it happened to use.

Are there any tools which can take a query and tell you which procs are, or at the very least suggest could be, syntactically equal to your query?  Or, barring that, what methods do you use to ensure you don't have multiple procs containing the same query written slightly differently?

Answer (score 2):

Using (and enforcing!) consistent naming standards should go a long way in preventing duplicates. Always use the same style (my preference is `entity_action`, e.g. `Customer_Update`). If all your objects are consistently named, it becomes pretty hard to create a duplicate unless you're completely ignoring the standard.

I realize that doesn't help you now - I don't know of any way to determine this unless you either grep by brute force or try to match query plans in `sys.dm_exec_cached_plans` to see if similar/identical plans refer to different objects. Neither of these things are trivial.

Answer (score 2):

This might find some dupes as long as the plans for the stored procs are in cache. (The query_hash and query_plan_hash are explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645887.aspx))

```
WITH qs AS
(
SELECT *, 
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY query_hash) qh,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY query_plan_hash) qph
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats 
)
SELECT 
       db_name(dbid) as database_name,
       object_name(objectid,dbid) as object_name,
       text,
         SUBSTRING(st.text, ( qs.statement_start_offset / 2 ) + 1, (
              ( CASE qs.statement_end_offset
              WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)
              ELSE qs.statement_end_offset END -
       qs.statement_start_offset ) / 2 ) + 1) AS statement_text,
                query_hash,
       query_plan_hash 
FROM qs
CROSS APPLY  sys.dm_exec_sql_text (qs.sql_handle) st
WHERE qh>1 OR qph>1
ORDER BY qh, qph
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the reasons I'm not a huge fan of stored procedures - managability becomes a real issue.

As Aaron Bertrand says, naming conventions go a long way with this, but if you haven't followed any particular convention, that won't solve your problem.

I don't think there's an out-of-the-box solution for this - but I think you could at least simplify your search by using sp_depends.

So, if you are looking for a proc that affects tables a, b and c, running sp_depends with a, b and c and seeing which procs turn up for all 3 would at least tell you which of the 600 procs you need to read through.

sp_depends doesn't report procs using dynamic sql.

Comment: And in SQL Server 2008 it might be better to use sys.sql_dependencies, sys.sql_expression_dependencies, sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities, sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities. sp_depends is pretty unreliable IMHO. I wrote about this a few years ago: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2008/09/09/keeping-sysdepends-up-to-date-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Comment: If the alternative to stored procedures is adhoc SQL that is surely less manageable? At least all the stored procedures are in one place not scattered around (possibly multiple) code bases.

Comment: Yes I also raised my eyebrow about the manageability comment. Any tech can be manageable if you use it right; the opposite is also true.